# Cut a string and paste it in a List?

Tags: string, unity-game-engine, substring, split

I have a string like that:

```
 string exampleStr = "0123456789 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
```

Now I want to write a function like that:

```
 private void StringCut(string str, int cut) {

     //... Cut string and put it in a string list

 }
```

You can give the string to a function with an int value.

E.g.

```
 StringCut(exampleStr, 5);
```

Now the function should cut the string in 5 pieces and put the string pieces in a List.

How can I do that?

I tried to split the string with:

```
 exampleStr.Substring(... , ... ));
```

But it's a lot of work. Is there a fast way to do that?

I don't tried exampleStr.Split, because the text and the length of the string is always different.

Comment: How do you determine length of each piece?

Comment: E.g. String length is 73. I want to cut it to 3 pieces (73/3 = 24.33...). So I add 24 chars in list[0], 24 chars in list[1], 9 chars (rest) to list[2]. It's like cut and join the string.

Comment: Substring inside a loop is the best way to do it. Just calculate length of each piece and shift it position every cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it. If someone needs it.

C# code:

```
private int maxStrLength = 30;

private List<string> StringCut(string getStr, int cut) {

    List<string> strToList = new List<string>();

    int getStringLength = getStr.Length;

    if (getStringLength > maxStrLength) {

        // GREATER

        float tmpDiv = (float)getStringLength/(float)maxStrLength;

        int roundTmpDiv = (int)System.Math.Ceiling(tmpDiv);

        for (int i = 0; i < roundTmpDiv; i++) {

            string tmpStr = "";

            if (i != roundTmpDiv-1) {

                tmpStr = getStr.Substring(i*maxStrLength, maxStrLength);

            } else {

                int rest = getStr.Length-((roundTmpDiv-1)*maxStrLength);

                tmpStr = getStr.Substring(i*maxStrLength, rest);

            }

            strToList.Add(tmpStr);

        }

    } else {

        // LOWER

        strToList.Add(getStr);
    }

    return strToList;

}

void Start() {

    string testString = "0123456789 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    List<string> tmpStr = StringCut (testString, 2);

    foreach (string tmpString in tmpStr){
        print (tmpString);
    }

}
```

Please post your code here, if you have a better solution.